# Discriminant of n-degree polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The discriminants of polynomials $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n, 1\leq n\leq 4$ are

| degree-n | discriminant-$\Delta_n$ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | $a_1^2-4a_2$ |
| 3 | $a_1^2a_2^2-27a_3^2-4a_1^3a_3-4a_2^3+18a_1a_2a_3$ |
| 4 | $a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2-256a_4^3+\cdots$ (16 items) |

Explicit formula for each $n$ can be obtained by the symmetric polynomial $\prod\limits_{i<j}(α_i−α_j)^2$. My question is

> **Is there a general term for $\Delta_n$?**

---

I'm trying to find the pattern of these multinomials, a feasible way (I guess) is to convert them into determinants.
For example

- $\Delta_1=1$
- $\Delta_2=\begin{array}{|cc|}a_1^2&4\\a_2&1\end{array}$.
- $\Delta_3$ has 5 items | 3-order determinant has 6 items
- $\Delta_4$ has 16 items | 4-order determinant has 24 items

I tried finding the determinant of $\Delta_3$ by hand but failed.
Since MMA has a lot of useful functions in guessing number pattern such as [FindSequenceFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) and [FindLinearRecurrence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLinearRecurrence.html), I wonder:

> **Is there exists an effective algorithm to convert multinomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ into determinants of order k with entries in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$.**

Note: Here one might require the determinant to be as "nontrivial" as possible. For instance, each entry of the determinant has the lowest degree.

Comment: The discriminant of a polynomial P is the resultant of the pair P and P' . The resultant can be calculated as a determinant from the formula here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition
So it's the determinant of a 2n-1 matrix containing coefficients from P and P' . Eg in the 2 case you get 
{{1, a_1, a_2 },
{1, 2*  a_1 0 },
 { 0 ,  1 ,  2 * a1}}

Comment: An in-depth introduction to discriminants and resultants is found in "Algorithms in real algebraic geometry" by Richard M. Pollack and Saugata Basu

Comment: Have you see the `Discriminant`command? There is `Modulus` option.

Comment: You can form a matrix to take the determinant using the Sylvester or Bezout formulation. Example: `In[414]:= poly[a_, x_, n_] := x^n + Array[a, n, 0] . x^Range[0, n - 1]

In[417]:= 
ResourceFunction["SylvesterMatrix"][poly[a, x, 4], 
 D[poly[a, x, 4], x], x]

Out[417]= {{1, a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0], 0, 0}, {0, 1, a[3], a[2], a[1],
   a[0], 0}, {0, 0, 1, a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0]}, {4, 3 a[3], 2 a[2], 
  a[1], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 3 a[3], 2 a[2], a[1], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 
  3 a[3], 2 a[2], a[1], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 3 a[3], 2 a[2], a[1]}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. This function is great!